# NSScrollView -- Not showing blue button scroll bar when < 4 rows?

Tags: cocoa, nsscrollview

Cocoa isn't rendering the blue scroll button unless my scroll view is 4 rows long.

[image: Screenshot comparing three table views, one with two rows and no scroll thumb and two with four rows each and a scroll thumb each.]
<sub>(source: [gordonjl.com](http://gordonjl.com/files/no_scroll_button.png))</sub>

Does anyone know how to show the scroll bar button when the scroll view is only two rows?

Thanks!

Comment: The name of the “blue button” is “scroll thumb”.

Comment: The NSScroller documentation refers to it as the "knob".  I think the term "thumb" is from Carbon.

Comment: I checked the Mac OS X HIG, and it says “scroller” refers to the knob/thumb alone: http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/applehiguidelines/XHIGWindows/XHIGWindows.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000961-TPXREF26 I haven't heard it called that anywhere else. Knob sounds good to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it's the number of rows, but that there just isn't enough room for the "blue button" and the scroll arrows.  You need to increase the height of your table.  It would be hard to use at that size anyway.

Comment: Agreed.  It seems like that's the only option to get the scroll bar to render properly.  Thanks for the input

Comment: At that size, a popup button is almost certainly a better fit